# i want to create domains for different users

Tags: php, cakephp, dns

I have domains like `www.football.com` and `www.baseball.com`.

They are linked with `www.game.com`, which is the parent, and its admin page, `www.game.com/admin`.

i want to create something like `www.football.com/userid1/admin`, `www.baseball.com/userid2/admin`, etc. for different users.

All the domains are mapped to same IP and there is only one admin folder. If I use CakePHP, is it possible to achieve the above?

Comment: This is more a ServerFault question. You'll need to set it up in Apache (or whatever web-server you're using) to point the domains to the same folder or handler script

Comment: Can you provide more detail as what you are trying to accomplish? If you use the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] method described below, code maintenance will be a huge concern. What is the goal of what you are trying to do by setting up the domains like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to do, but gets nitpicky in the details. You configure Apache to point all those domains to the same set of PHP files, then you simply check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to see which domain was actually requested:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
   case 'www.baseball.com':
   case 'baseball.com':
        // do baseball.com stuff here
        break;
   case 'www.football.com':
   case 'football.com':
        // football stuff here
    default:
       // just in case no valid hostname was given (e.g. coming in via IP only)
       // do default stuff here
}
```

With appropriate care in the rest of your code and templates, you can easily determine which site's images/stylesheets/content to output, but basically use the same core logic for all of them.